# error "time" is not defined: UndefinedVariable

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

```
def time_stats(df):
    start_time = time.time()
```

When I run this code in VS Code it does run fine, however "time" is underlined:
[image: underlined word]

and if I hover with the mouse there, I see an error message from PyLance that states:

```
"time" is not defined: UndefinedVariable
```

I did `import time` at the start of my file though and couldn't find clues in https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time.

I guess this is not a big issue but since I'm learning I would love to have some advice so that I can avoid bad habits from the start.

Comment: Sounds like a VS Code or PyLance problem, not so much Python. You may want to add the `VS Code` and/or [pylance] tags to your question, so people selecting on those tagsmay find your question more easily.

Comment: Apparently PyLance has a lot of problems with this, google autocompleted *"pylance no"* to *"pylance not detecting imports"*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode settings for Pylance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65200732/vscode-settings-for-pylance) (and try to add your python libs directory to the list perhaps?)

Comment: Thank you all! I'm glad to hear that it's probably not something to do with my code.

Comment: @maud Could you run your code correctly? And can you enable flake8 linter? You can add this in your settings.json file: "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,

Comment: @maud And could you reload your VScode to have a try? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine. few things you can check

- Try disabling `pylance`.
- if you are using python linters(pylint) then you might need to disable that too. check this [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1154) for more details.

  `python.linting.pylintEnabled": false` use  this code to disable pylint in your setting.json file.

Let me know if this helps.